# Eclipse RCP; what is the use of the 'description' field of a org.eclipse.ui.commands command?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

When adding a command to the extension `org.eclipse.ui.commads`, there is a field '**name**' and a field '**description**'. The name field seems to be used at most places. When will description be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`org.eclipse.ui.commands` schema page](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_commands.html) mentions:

> description - A translatable short description of this command for display in the UI.

This is typically visible in Eclipse GUI where the commands need to be displayed, like in the "Command Groups Availability" of the "Customize Perspective" dialog:

[image]

<sup>(from [Customizing the Eclipse User Interface](http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6-Beta/html/Developer_Guide/eclipseide-customize.html))</sup>

---

Note: the status bar is for status message only and won't display those command descriptions. See [Eclipse UI Guideline 9.9](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-UI-Guidelines/Contents.html).

Comment: Thanks. Hmmm... I think I understand what you mean, but I can't see any descriptions in the status bar, either in Eclipse or in my own RCP application. I would really appreciate an example :-)

Comment: @Peteter: right, the status bar is not a good example. I have added a dialog box which shows those descriptions in action.